# Different values for intercept estimate in linear regression

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, intercept

I'm reading about linear regression from two sources. In here: https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat415/lesson/7/7.3 the estimate for the intercept is just $\bar y$.

However over here: https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter8/8_5_3_the_method_of_least_squares.php the estimate is given by $\hat \beta_0=\bar y-\hat\beta_1\bar x$.

I'm confused as to why there are conflicting values for the intercept estimate. What am I missing here?

Comment: The intercept is the estimate when all the other coefficients are zero.

Comment: @mdewey: But the intercept, as I understand it, is where the estimated regression line intersects the y axis. Surely this can't just be $\bar y$? Imagine an $x-y$ scatter plot that's sloping up and roughly linear and suppose the intercept value is $a$. Let's say you horizontal mirror-flip the chart. Clearly the $\bar y$ and $\bar x$ values stay the same, BUT the intercept will surely be higher than before, i.e., $>a$. And this is because the slope changes. The definition of intercept as the estimate when all other coefficients are zero doesn't agree with the y axis intersection definition?

Comment: If the line is sloping then the slope cannot be zero so your Gedankenexperiment is not relevant.

Comment: @mdewey: could you elaborate what's meant by not relevant? Lines are usually sloping in linear regression

Comment: In the second example you need to set $\beta_1$ to zero to get the equivalence.